# Register MySQL function in Hibernate dialect with variable number of arguments

Tags: mysql, hibernate, mysql-8.0

We can easily register functions such as these:

```
registerFunction("JSON_EXTRACT", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "JSON_EXTRACT(?1, ?2)"));

registerFunction("JSON_UNQUOTE", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "JSON_UNQUOTE(?1)"));
```

But how would I register a function that takes a variable number of arguments?

```
registerFunction("JSON_SET", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "JSON_SET(?1, ?2, ?3, ...)"));
```

`JSON_SET` is defined as: `JSON_SET(json_doc, path, val[, path, val] ...)`

It takes at least 3 arguments, but up to any number to perform multiple replacements. It is not an option in my use case to call `JSON_SET` multiple times -- I need to be able to pass an unknown number of `path`/`val` arguments into the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to use `StandardSQLFunction` instead of `SQLFunctionTemplate`. The latter appears to be intended for a SQL function that doesn't follow the normal format: `SOME_FUNC(var1, var2, ...)`